# должны содержать не менее одной (о

Tags: дефект, дизайн

На мете сообщение

> должны содержать не менее одной (обсуждение дефект поддержка предложение)

показывается в плейсхолдере в урезанном виде:

> [image: скриншот поля ввода]

При этом в разметке видно текст целиком:

[image: скриншот разметки]

Пользуюсь браузером:

> **Google Chrome** 74.0.3729.157 (Официальная сборка) (64 бит) (cohort: Stable)
>   **Версия**  7b16107ab85c5364cdcd0b2dea2539a1f2dc327a-refs/branch-heads/3729@{#998}
>   **ОС**  Windows 10 OS Build 17763.503
>   **JavaScript**  V8 7.4.288.28
>   **Flash**   32.0.0.192 C:\Windows\system32\Macromed\Flash\pepflashplayer64_32_0_0_192.dll
>   **User Agent**  Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/74.0.3729.157 Safari/537.36

Comment: Проблема в `style="width: 19px"` при min-width=230px

Comment: вообще, странное решение размещать общий плейсхолдер в поле ввода одного тега. [img](https://imgur.com/UgJVz7a.png)

Comment: Проблема на всех сайтах не только у нас. Будет время, опубликуй на метамете, там быстрее посмотрят.

Comment: Ubuntu, Firefox 47.0 - тоже воспроизводится